# Python 3 equivalent of Python 2 center

Tags: python

The following Works in Python 2

```
print ("|").center(11,'-')
```

When I try the same code in Python 3 I get the following error Message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

How would one do the same thing in Python 3?

Comment: FWIW, you can also center using the `.format` method:  `'{:-^11}'.format('centered')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> print("|".center(11, '-'))
-----|-----
```

In Python 3 `print` is a function so you need to do the centering inside - otherwise you'd call it on the return value of `print`.

---

Additionally, in Python 2 you should not put parentheses there at all:

```
>>> print "|".center(11, '-')
-----|-----
```

The reason why it works with parentheses is that `(foo)` and `foo` are the same thing.

Another option to make it work in both Python 2 and Python 3 would be to add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of your file and then use the Python 3 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`print` a function, so your code in Python 3 is calling `center()` on the return value of `print` function (which is None). 
Add one more pair of parenthesis:

```
print( ("|").center(11,'-') )
```

Answer (score 0):

An f-string solution would be;

```
print(f'{"|":-^11}')
```